# SQL WITH keyword inside CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Observing some strange behavior when using WITH keyword inside CURSOR:

```
WITH minuteList (aMinute) AS
    (
        SELECT @startTime UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, aMinute)
        FROM minuteList
        WHERE aMinute < DATEADD(MINUTE, 9, @startTime)
    )
SELECT * FROM minuteList
```

The above code works perfectly creating a table with one aMinute column and 10 datetime rows with 1 minute interval. However, the code below enters into an infinite loop printing only @startTime value endlessly.

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    WITH minuteList (aMinute) AS
    (
        SELECT @startTime UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, aMinute)
        FROM minuteList
        WHERE aMinute < DATEADD(MINUTE, 9, @startTime)
    )
    SELECT * FROM minuteList
OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @laterTime
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT @laterTime
END
CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

Can someone explain what's happening and why the infinite loop occurs?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to stick this into a **cursor**?? Avoid cursors like the plague!

Comment: @Matthew Haugen No, mate, this gives incorrect syntax near DECLARE cursor1

Comment: `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0`. FETCH_STATUS is never manipulated, so when does it ever change from 0 to terminate the loop?

Comment: @CodeNewbie @@FETCH_STATUS is a global variable, I think it's changed when cursor runs out of values to iterate.

Comment: Are you sure it changes when the cursor completes its iterations? Inspect that.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Thank you, mate, stupid me forgot to put FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO laterTime inside while loop, answer it and I vote you as correct.

Comment: Lol, didn't see your comment and painstakingly wrote out an elaborate answer. :P Oh well, let's hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a line-by-line analysis of your cursor call to explain why it goes into an infinite loop.

```
OPEN cursor1                             // Opens your cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @laterTime  // Takes the first row returned by the
                                            cursor and inserts it into the 
                                            variable @laterTime
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN           // Checks if the next value has been
                                            fetched and executes
                                            the code inside the loop
PRINT @laterTime                         // Prints the current row
END                                      // Ends the loop when FETCH_STATUS is 
                                            not 0 (when fetch fails).
CLOSE cursor1;                           // Closes the cursor.
```

The cause for the infinite loop is the fact that @@FETCH_STATUS is never changed because you have accessed only the first row from the cursor (the fetch has not failed because it has not been called more than once). After printing @laterTime, you need to fetch the next value of the cursor inside the loop. And only when that fetch fails will the loop terminate.

Consider [this example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) as a reference.

Modified code will look like this:

```
OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @laterTime
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT @laterTime
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @laterTime
END
CLOSE cursor1;
```